# python-codingbat chocalate question. code i have written has no syntax error, yet does not provide output

Tags: python

We want make a package of goal kilos of chocolate. We have small bars (1 kilo each) and big bars (5 kilos each). Return the number of small bars to use, assuming we always use big bars before small bars. Return -1 if it can't be done.

```py
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal): 
  for i in range(1, big + 1):
    for x in range(small + 1):
      if x + (5 * i) == goal:
         return x
      else:
         return -1
    
make_chocolate(4, 1, 9)
```

What's wrong with this code? does it have to do anything with the nested loop and condition inside it? when i run, it shows timed out.

link to the problem in codebate website:
https://codingbat.com/prob/p190859

Comment: You're returning `-1` as soon as a combination of `x` and `i` fails; get rid of the `else:` and move the `return -1` after both for loops.

Answer (score 0):

So in your specific code the problem is in the `if` statement.
It returns -1 before it ever has a chance to try any number other than one small piece.

```
if x+ (5*i)== goal:
    return x
else:
    return -1
```

Part of the reason you are in that if statement is because the code you have is the nested `for` loops instead of independently tracking the 5 counts and the 1 counts.

Breaking it into separate loops would make the tracking of how many pieces you need much easier. Take out all the 5 pieces, that you have, from the goal amount. Once you do that, you won't even need a second loop to compare the small pieces, because then you can just do a simple `if-else` check on the sizes of goal and small.

Since at this point you are switching to a single loop and because you are trying to figure out how many big to take out of the goal, a `while` loop becomes cleaner. This is because you are no longer tracking something in a range and instead doing something until a condition is met.

**Final Code:**

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    while big > 0:
        if goal - 5 >= 0:
            goal -= 5
        else:
            break

    if small >= goal:
        return goal
    else:
        return -1
```

Also note here, that since there is not a nested loop anymore, this code just went from O(n)^2 time space to O(n) time space. So it's much more efficient now.